# Different SSH/RDP hosts based on location

Tags: network, ssh, geolocation

I have a few servers that I ssh and RDP to to at my office.  When I'm out of the office I connect to them via hamachi.  Currently I have duplicate ssh hosts and rdp profiles for inside and outside the office.  I'd like a solution that switched these automatically based on my location.  I've looked at the network locations but that doesn't seem to do what I'd like it to.

Comment: Do you use local DNS inside Hamachi and have access to your company's DNS records? You could create a similar entry for the respective IPs.

Comment: onik no, I access everything via ipv4.